# Creating layer with WFS, but no features are added to the layer

Tags: python, wfs, qgsvectorlayer

I am creating a plugin that is gathering data from a WFS client. The WFS client was recently updated, and I had to update the URL and filter encoding that I was using. I updated the code, and it is now working fine on one computer, but when I later tested on another computer, it did not. It creates a layer as normal, but no features are put into it. I think my URL is not encoded correctly, but I am not sure what is incorrect in it.

I create the layer with QgsVectorLayer("url", "name, "ogr") and then QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer). I am trying to encode the URL by changing some of the values:

```
< : %3C
> : %3E
space : %20
" : %22
```

An example of a URL and filter encoding that works on one computer, but not others:

```
url: http://wfs.geonorge.no/skwms1/wfs.tilgjengelighet_tettsted?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857&typeNames=app:TettstedInngangBygg&

filther encoding: FILTER=<fes:Filter xmlns:app="http://skjema.geonorge.no/SOSI/produktspesifikasjon/TilgjengelighetTettsted/1.2"><fes:PropertyIsEqualTo><fes:ValueReference>app:kommune</fes:ValueReference><fes:Literal>0301</fes:Literal></fes:PropertyIsEqualTo></fes:Filter>
```

After I have changed some of the characters to encode it, it looks like this:

```
http://wfs.geonorge.no/skwms1/wfs.tilgjengelighet_tettsted?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857&typeNames=app:TettstedInngangBygg&FILTER=%3Cfes:Filter%20xmlns:app=%22http://skjema.geonorge.no/SOSI/produktspesifikasjon/TilgjengelighetTettsted/1.2%22%3E%3Cfes:PropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3Cfes:ValueReference%3Eapp:kommune%3C/fes:ValueReference%3E%3Cfes:Literal%3E0301%3C/fes:Literal%3E%3C/fes:PropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3C/fes:Filter%3E
```

If i run them in a web browser, I get results, but it also says in the top: numberMatched="unknown" numberReturned="0"

I am hoping someone can see what I am doing wrong or are able to point me in the right direction. I have lost a lot of time because it appears to be working on my main computer, and I didn't have a lot of time for testing.

Comment: http://wfs.geonorge.no/skwms1/wfs.tilgjengelighet_tettsted?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857&typeNames=app:TettstedInngangBygg&FILTER=<fes:Filter%20xmlns:app="http://skjema.geonorge.no/SOSI/produktspesifikasjon/TilgjengelighetTettsted/1.2"><fes:PropertyIsEqualTo><fes:ValueReference>app:kommune</fes:ValueReference><fes:Literal>0301</fes:Literal></fes:PropertyIsEqualTo></fes:Filter>&resultType=hits gives me `numberMatched="548" numberReturned="0`

Comment: and the no filter query http://wfs.geonorge.no/skwms1/wfs.tilgjengelighet_tettsted?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=2.0.0&srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857&typeNames=app:TettstedInngangBygg&resultType=hits gives me `numberMatched="7462" numberReturned="0"` so the filter encoding seems correct

Comment: `The WFS client was recently updated, and I had to update the URL and filter encoding that I was using` when you say you had to update the URL, is that because the service also changed?  Did you have to change the version of the WFS service you were calling?  What media type/ encoding is your client application expecting?

Comment: @nmtoken They change some of the attributes, so I had to use a different query. Some attributes was put into an datatype, so in the query I had to access it to the datatye. I had some trouble making it work that way, but I think I found the right structure in the end